# authorize.net payment distribution

Tags: php, paypal, authorize.net

I am looking for the solution on authorize.net payment distribution.

Eg: there is 3 person and site admin (A,B,C & site admin)

A want to send money to C using the site.

now the money A is sending is automatically going to divide in some part...

Amount 1 -> site owner will charge some % as commission on the amount(lets say 2%).

Amount 2 -> B will get some money (lets say $100) (for some extra service which is predefined)

Amount 3 -> we also required to less the charges of Transaction fee which paypal or authorize.net etc will charge.

Amount 4 -> is the amount which C will receive in last.

Also A can pay using any account (CR. card, DR. card, Paypal, authorize.net etc) type (but the process will use Authorize.net for transaction)

And C & B get the money.

Que :
How can i do this using authorize.net ?

Also Do we required to have B's & C's account account on Authorize or they can get money on any account type(like paypal, authorize etc).?

And how can i get the changes details and deduct it from the actual amount.?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with Authorize.Net. Currently your only real solution is to use [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) which is designed for this very scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP in response to your answer, you could potentially do it IF they had an authorize.net account as well.  The PHP API requires the api key for the merchant the money is going to.  Think of Authorize.net as a middle man between the customer and your bank account, not like Paypal which holds on to money in it's own bank account system.  Since that is the case, I am almost positive you can't transfer money between accounts or pay someone using your Authorize.net API.

If you had their Authorize.net API, it would show up as 2 separate charges on their card of different amounts, which would probably not be good as the client would think that they are being charged twice.  Overall I don't think that would be a smart move.

If you wanted to, you could use a Paypal account that is also tied to that same bank account, and then possibly use Paypal's API after the charge goes through to divvy up the payment.

Ultimately, I personally think the best way to go about it is one single charge to the customer, and then figuring out a way to cut a check or send a payment to the other parties involved.  Multiple small charges and 1 big charge are sure going to look suspicious.

Anyone else that has any experience, feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: thanks alot for quick reply...  how about if customer have any account with the random bank... so how can i make the above thing possible...?